# Pages does not find my PHP includes

Tags: php

I am having an include folder with haeder.inc.php, nav.inc.php and footer.inc.php.

So, I do want to organize my php pages by sections.

I mean, I do want to have a pic folder, then a video folder and put inside all php pages related to each folder.

**Problems** The php pages does not find my include folder (haeder.inc.php, nav.inc.php and footer.inc.php.)

I hope it makes sense.

Comment: it doesn't. With no code example it doesn't make any sense

Comment: try using require_once, it will show you where it looks if it fails

Comment: @Nayena your comment makes no sense. include() will raise the same error

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel, didn't know this - i have always used require_once because include failed on me a couple of years ago

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specify the full path instead of just the filename, e.g. `./header.inc.php`.

Comment: didn't you mean `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/header.inc.php';`

Comment: well, it will help nothing then

Comment: @Col.: It will when `.` is not in `include_dir`.

Answer (score 1):

are you using relative path ? if yes doublecheck about what your current dir is or try using absolute path

Answer (score 0):

Specify full path by using a relative one like this:

```
require_once(dirname(__FILE__).'/../file.php');
```

or if your php version allows:

```
require_once(__DIR__.'/../file.php');
```

Both constructions include a file which path is provided relative to the current one.